# how to get perticular string from json String

Tags: json, string

Below is my json string getting response from server. in this strig i want alternateLink String part which is "**https://drive.google.com/file/d/2ferg6YSxertrewtaN_1iZc/view**" how i can get this in another string variable

```
    {
       "kind": "drive#file",

       "id": "2ferg6YSxertrewtaN_1G2re-5PDygeg",

       "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/2ferg6YSxertrewtaN_1iZc/view?usp=drivesdk",

       "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/2fl6YSxfNweQwtaN_1G2IzuK-5PDyFwrc/preview?usp=drivesdk"
    }
```

Comment: Deserialize the response into apex wrapper class and get the value from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper class and use it further to get value of whatever field value required like follow:

```
public class sampleWrapperClass {

public String kind;
public String id;
public String alternateLink;
public String embedLink;


public static sampleWrapperClass  parse(String json) {
    return (sampleWrapperClass) System.JSON.deserialize(json, sampleWrapperClass.class);
}
}
```

Now that you have your wrapper structure ready, you can do following to get value of field `alternatelink` , execute following  in `execute anonymous` window of  `developer console`

```
sampleWrapperClass  objWrapper = sampleWrapperClass.parse(passYourJson);
system.debug('****objWrapper.alternateLink****'+objWrapper.alternateLink);
```

This will give you,

```
****objWrapper.alternateLink****https://drive.google.com/file/d/2ferg6YSxertrewtaN_1iZc/view?usp=drivesdk
```